# EKS + NLB: `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: true` not working with `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb`

Tags: amazon-elb, amazon-eks, nlb, internal-load-balancer

I have an EKS Kubernetes 1.16.x. cluster with three public subnets tagged with `kubernetes.io/role/elb: 1` and three private subnets tagged with `kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb: 1`

I'm attempting to create an internal NLB LoadBalancer service. By internal, I want it hosted on the three private subnets and not the three public subnets.

I'm following the docs at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/load-balancing.html

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: true
  name: grafana-nlb
  namespace: prometheus
spec:
  ports:
    - name: service
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: prom
    app.kubernetes.io/name: grafana
  type: LoadBalancer
```

If I omit the `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: true` annotation, everything seems to work perfectly and produce exactly what I expect. I get a public NLB that is hosted on the three public subnets only. I can see this via the AWS cli with `aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers`, with `"Scheme": "internet-facing"`, `"Type": "network",`.

If create this with the `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: true` annotation, I get a classic ELB rather than an NLB, and it's still public. It has `"Scheme": "internet-facing"` and is hosted on the three public subnets only. With the CLI, I can see the load balancer with `aws elb describe-load-balancers` but not with `aws elbv2 describe-load-balancers`

This seems like broken behavior. Any tips on how I can troubleshoot or proceed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `true` needs to be quoted as `"true"` in the yaml.

This works:

```yaml
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
```

This causes the error I was experiencing:

```yaml
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: true
```